# How to make sure that cache is of for an object in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, caching, cache-control

Please refer to the below code:

```
<% 
UserDetails ud = UserService.getUserDetails();
%>
```

How do I make sure that "ud" is not cached and can provide updated data. Every time I refresh the page I need the updated values from the back end as the values may change. But I am suspecting in my application the value is cached and hence it shows the previous information all the time when I load the page.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Note: I am not referring to browser cache here. I just want updated values of "ud" every time i refresh the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Browser cache **is** almost the only cache. JSPs are compiled to servlets. Servlets don't cache. `UserService` might cache; check there.

Comment: @Elliot I didnt developed the application. how do i know if we are cacheing. Can you please let me know how to verify this.

Comment: I didn't developed the application either. Hire a developer.

Comment: @Elliot. Sorry. I didnt mean you to check the code :) I dont know the method of caching in code. I will try looking into some websites. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: Put the application in debug mode > put the breakpoint on your getUserDetails() > traverse step by step your program and find out whether it get's value from database or from cached values.